# Trouble creating own mailserver

Tags: mail-server, haraka

I am creating own mail server. I am using Haraka (http://haraka.github.io/). But I am little confused about the relay thing. How to make relay my mail server so that I can send mail using other domain(DKIM and SPF verified).

I want mail in receiver inbox not in Spam. Right now mail is received in spam. What is relay in particular ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've got is that you're having a problem with sending mail on behalf of "other domain".

Given that "other domain" mail reaches its destination (even in SPAM folder) I assume that you've configured your relay right.

Key thing to notice is that DKIM and SPF records not only need to be validated but also need to be aligned with your "other domain". It's a common scenario when SPF/DKIM validations 'pass' but overall DMARC policy 'fails'.

Providing both your message headers (to check how it was processed) and your other domain name (to check how SPF/DKIM/DMARC records configured) would help a lot.

Comment: thanks for the answer. In my scenario all things passed. Now I used mail in box (https://mailinabox.email). And as per your suggestion all things are passed. You can see : https://www.mail-tester.com/web-d2ofm
But still it goes to spam folder in gmail. So I am asking will gmail block my IP if I test more ?
And getting in spam will stop my dream to become a email service provider ? Or I ll move forward with its R&D

Comment: Passing DMARC does not guarantee that your mail will bypass receiver's spam filter.

I've just checked my Spam folder in Gmail and have found a mail from Airbnb.

Gmail says it's there because: "**Why is this message in Spam?** It's similar to messages that have been detected by our spam filters".

What does it say in your case?

I can't see your results from the mail-tester.com (maybe wrong link?), so providing your headers (and Gmail reason to mark your mail as Spam) would help.

Comment: Another thing that you must do is have a valid PTR record (reverse DNS) in the reverse DNS zone of your IP provider. 
So if your emails are sent from mail.domain.com than there should be a PTR pointing from your mail server IP to that domain.